# Update datepicker value based on php condition

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement, datepicker

I want to update jquery datepicker values based on a php condition. Is it possible to do it. If yes means please help me.

```
<?php if ($newDateTime > $queryStart) { 
    ?> 
<script> $(function(){ $('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker({ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', }); }); 
    <?php } else { ?> 
    <script> $(function(){ $('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker({ format: 'yyyy/mm/dd', }); }); </script> 
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: with php you could do some echo of javascript function to update datePicker regardless of php condition

Comment: if ( $newDateTime > $queryStart){
                ?>
                 <script>
                 $(function(){
                
                  $('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker({
                                           format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', });  }); </script> <?php else {
                ?>
                 <script>
                 $(function(){
                  $('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker({
                                           format: 'yyyy/mm/dd', }); }); </script> <?php } ?>

Comment: can you provide some code please.

Comment: here i executed script based on php condition, but it is not working. I also tried by echo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                                                        if ( '<?php echo $currentDateTime; ?>' > '<?php echo $queryStart; ?>' ){
                                                                $('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker({
                                                                        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                                                                        changeMonth: true,
                                                                        changeYear: true,
                                                                        minDate: 0,
                                                                        autoclose: true,
                                                                        startDate: '+1d'
                                                                    });
                                                        }

                                                        else {
                                                            $('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker({
                                                                        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                                                                        changeMonth: true,
                                                                        changeYear: true,
                                                                        minDate: 0,
                                                                        autoclose: true,
                                                                        startDate: '+0d'
                                                                    });
                                                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors,

For current code

you have not closed `if()` so just add `}` before `else {`

Final code

```
<?php if ($newDateTime > $queryStart) { ?> 
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', });
        });
    </script> 
<?php } else { ?> //  <----- } for if is missing
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker({format: 'yyyy/mm/dd', });
        });
    </script> 
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't shows datepicker properly

Comment: Thanks for co-operation, i did it by different way. Now it is working.